# Prove that $|\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}|=\mathbf{0}$ As per following condition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

### If $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are real orthogonal matrices of the same order and $|\mathbf{B}|+|\mathbf{A}|=\mathbf{0}$
Prove that $|\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}|=\mathbf{0}$

---

**My Approach:-**

$|\mathrm{A}|+|\mathrm{B}|=0$

$\Rightarrow|A|=-|B|$

$|\mathrm{A}| \cdot|\mathrm{B}|=-1 \quad\left[\because|\mathrm{B}|=\left|B^{-1}\right| \text {as they are orthogonal }\right]$

Let, $C=A\left(A^{T}+B^{T}\right) B$

$\Rightarrow|C|=\left|A A^{T} B+A B^{T} B\right|=|B+A| \ldots \ldots \ldots$ (i)

And $|\mathrm{C}|=|\mathrm{A}|\left|A^{T}+B^{T}\right||B|=-\left|A^{T}+B^{T}\right|$

$\Rightarrow-\left|(A+B)^{T}\right|=-|A+B| \ldots \ldots \ldots \ldots$ (ii)

$|A+B|=-|A+B|$

$\Rightarrow 2|A+B|=0$

$\boxed{\Rightarrow|A+B|=0}$

*I am looking for another short approach.Any alternate solution would be greatly appreciated*

Comment: Personally, I think it is an optimal solution.

Comment: thanks! but I am feeling not that much excited while come to conclusion in this way.that's why i am asking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\norm[1]{\lVert #1 \rVert}$Here is a proof that I think gives more intuition. Let $X$ be a real orthogonal matrix.

**Lemma 1.** $|\lambda(X)| = 1$

**Proof.**  $Xu=\lambda u \Rightarrow |\lambda|^2 \lVert u \rVert^2 = \lVert Xu \rVert^2 = u^* X^TXu = \lVert u \rVert^2$

**Lemma 2.** If $|X|=-1$ then $X$ has an odd number of $-1$ eigenvalue.

**Proof.** If $\lambda$ is complex then $\bar{\lambda}$ is also an eigenvalue of $X$.  So, $-1=|X|=\prod_i \lambda_i = (-1)^k$ since multiplication of other eigenvalues results in $1$.

**Answer.** $|A|+|B|=0 \Rightarrow |A^TB| = -1$, which means $A^TB$ (which is also orthogonal) has at least 1 eigenvalue of $-1$, so $|I+A^TB|=0$ and consequently $|A+B|=0$.

Comment: allright but I have some doubts. 1.|X|=+/- 1 ( If I take ve value then how can I proof ?)2.how |A^T B|=−1?? 3. Where have u used 1st lemma

Comment: @AmartyaRoy Since $\det A^T=\det A=-\det B$, you get that $\det(A^TB)=-(\det A)^2=-1$, because the determinant of an orthogonal matrix is either $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: @AmartyaRoy 1. I didn't understand. 2. is answered by egreg and by yourself actually in the question. 3. It is used to prove Lemma 2. Because of Lemma 1 product of all complex eigenvalues is equal to 1.

Comment: Yeah it is cleared to me.Thanks